# Enable secure websocket connection through NGINX Ingress on GKE

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, websocket, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been trying to connect to my websocket endpoint over https at `wss://api.mywebsite.com/ws/chat` from my frontend client.

I can't seem to figure out the correct NGINX configuration for my ingress on kubernetes to allow a connection. Currently the controller keeps logging a `426 needs upgrade` everytime I try to connect to the endpoint.

This is my current ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
      location /ws {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://ws;
      }

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mywebsite.com
        - api.mywebsite.com
      secretName: mywebsite-com
  rules:
    - host: api.mywebsite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: gateway-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /ws/*
            backend:
              serviceName: gateway-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
    - host: mywebsite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: gateway-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the following annotation (as found [here](https://pumpingco.de/blog/using-signalr-in-kubernetes-behind-nginx-ingress/)): `nginx.org/websocket-services: "gateway-cluster-ip-service"`

resulting in:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "gateway-cluster-ip-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
    ...
```